# core dump while executing java Gui

Tags: java

I'm new to java GUI.I just executed a code from a book .My core gets dumped.I'm able to run normal java programs.

**My code :**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Gui{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hey there");
        }
}
```

**The core dump message :**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f17b82ee009, pid=4640, tid=4641
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P" (or dumping to /home/gayathri/core.4640)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/gayathri/hs_err_pid4640.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Try using jdk / jre from oracle instead of open

Comment: I am not familiar with OpenJDK versioning, but the build date of April, 2016 suggests that you may want to check if there are newer versions available.